# How to view compiler error in Eclipse (Luna)?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-cloud

I am new to the Eclipse (Luna) IDE. I downloaded a sample bluemix node.js application, which I have opened in Eclipse. When I do "Build All", I do not see any information in either the "Console" or the "progress view" window. If I deliberately type anything wrong in the code window, I do not see any errors in either of this window. How do I know whether the code has been compiled properly and how do I know the errors if any?.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is an interpreted language, not a compiled language. There is no manual compile step where you can see compilation errors. If you've want the editor to assist you with syntax and content completion as you type, the nodeclipse plugin for Eclipse should help.